# $V=F_1^2$ over $F_2$: which operation to choose?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I don't understand the following vector space:
$$V=\{(x,y)|x,y\in F_1\}$$
and $V$ is over field $F_2$, ($F_1$ is a field too).
My question is:

Is $V$ really a vector space? I am not talking about the situation that $F_2\subset F_1$. An example that bothers me is: $F_1=R$  and $F_2=Z_p$ when $p$ is a prime. Let's assume that for any scalar $\alpha$: $\alpha * (x,y) =(\alpha x,\alpha y)$. Because I said $V$ is over $F_2$, $\alpha\in F_2$. When I calculate the term $\alpha x$, do I need to use the operations of $F_1$ or $F_2$? In this example the question is if to use mod $n$ calculation or the normal one of $R$? So who decides which operation do we use, $F_1$ or $F_2$?

Comment: I don't think there is a natural way in which $F_1^2$ is a vector space over $F_2$ without the assumption that $F_2 \subseteq F_1$ (or, at least, without a homomorphism $F_2 \to F_1$).

Answer (score 0):

I can present you with an example in order to try to make you understand the concept better.

Consider $F_1=\mathbb{C}$, $F_2=\mathbb{R}$. Then $V\cong\mathbb{C}^2$ seen as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, that means that you are allowed to multiply only by real numbers. In fact, you can easily see that $\dim_{\mathbb{R}} V = 4$, with a basis given by $(1,0)$, $(i,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(0,i)$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your example but the fields you mentioned have the same operation. I am asking about the case that the fields don't have the same operation, like $Z_p$ and $R$ for example.

Comment: @Sefi In that case you have to define a scalar multiplication satisfying the axioms, and study your field accordingly.